# How can I change the color of a label at certain index?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays, one with all the animals, and one with selectedAnimals. Wherever selectedAnimals equals animals have that label be a different color. Have cat, whale, bat be white and dog and sheep be black.

```
var animals = ["dog", "cat", "sheep", "whale", "bat"]
var selectedAnimals = ["cat, "whale", "bat"]

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: selectcell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! selectcell
    cell.animallabel.text = animals[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.animallabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is the array 'subject'?

Comment: Sorry I updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
cell.animallabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor
```

with

```
if (selectedAnimals.contains(animal[indexPath.row]) {
    cell.animallabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor
} else {
    cell.animallabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps shorter: `cell.animalLabel.textColor = selectedAnimals.contains(animal[indexPath.row]) ? .whiteColor() : .blackColor()` :)